# How to use Contact Form 7 and CCavenue in India need to pay a fixed amount at the end of registration

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment-gateway, contact-form-7, ccavenue

i have no that much exposure in wordpress,

I am planning to use Contact Form 7 for form submission (not wordpress account registration) on wordpress page and need to pay a fixed amount in Indian Rupees (currency) at the end of registration.

So i'm planning for Ccavenue as the payment process but don't know how to accomplish this.

(The registration form have file upload fields, several text fields as well.)

Can any one please guide me how to do this? I tried paypal plugin with contact form 7, but they only allow payment in USD. I need it in Indian Rupees

Any idea how to do this? Please show me or guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at Woocommerce, you can configure to accept Indian currency: http://teckstack.com/wordpress-woocommerce-setup-paypal-for-inr

Comment: Thank you but not helping in my situation here

Comment: Have you tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woocommerce ?